# I can't iterate over my table with the js map function from react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I entered to retrieve data from my database through through a laravel api.
As soon as I retrieve the data I store them in a react array that I created with usestate (const [tab, setTab] = useState ([]))
to add the data to retrieve in my table I do setTab ([... tab, data]). What sends me back all its
But I can't seem to walk it
thank you for helping me

[
[
{"id":4,"categorie_id":34,"libelle_analyse":"TVO","prix_unitaire":"5000","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2021-10-26T15:16:01.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-10-26T15:16:01.000000Z","libelle_categorie":"AT7"}
],[{"id":7,"categorie_id":31,"libelle_analyse":"TDOI","prix_unitaire":"7800","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2021-10-26T15:18:58.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-10-26T15:18:58.000000Z","libelle_categorie":"AT2"}]
]

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried so we can better see where the problem might be? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I notice that there double brackets around your data, I think you are getting array inside an array is that right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.